# Google Sheets – Is there a Full Screen Function or Script?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, full-screen

I was wondering if there is a function that makes google sheets go full screen? For example a script that can be added to picture, that when clicked makes google sheets go full screen? Or upon opening a document makes it go full screen?
Thank you very much :)

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 2):

There's not a function... but there is a shortcut in Windows:

<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> then <kbd>u</kbd>

that hides both the ribbon and status bar.

Comment: This could be combined with the some other steps to hide the web-browser tabs, address bar, bookmarks bar, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Comment: @RobertHeiber Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @RobertHeiber The question specifies [google-apps-script]. Remove the [google-apps-script] tag and add [keyboard-shortcuts] if that is what is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

That cannot be done with Apps Script, because scripts do not have access to the Google Sheets user interface on the level that would be required.